# Split array in groups of n, m, o groups or more

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

Is there any method to split an array like this?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].split(3, 4, 2)
#=> [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7],[8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is none, but you can easily write one yourself.

```
class Array
  def in_groups_of_n(*sizes)
   sizes.map(&method(:shift))
  end
end
```

*Example*:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr.in_groups_of_n(3, 4, 2)
# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/KaGK)

In case you want a none-destructive version, you can use a `dup` method:

```
class Array
  def in_groups_of_n(*sizes)
   duplicate = dup
   sizes.map { |size| duplicate.shift(size) }
  end
end

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr.in_groups_of_n(3,4,2)
# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]
arr
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/KaGK/1)

Comment: `shift` modifies the receiver.

Comment: Just add `a = dup` and operate off of `a` in the method.

Comment: I suggest you only give the non-destructive version. Generally, unless a destructive solution is specifically requested (which would make no sense here) I think we should assume that non-destructive solutions are desired. Moreover, here it's obvious how the non-destructive version could be altered to make it destructive.

Answer (score 2):

Immutable version with λ:

```
▶ splitter = ->(array, *parts) do 
    parts.reduce([[], 0]) do |acc, i|
      right = acc.last + i
      [acc.first << (acc.last...right), right]
    end.first.map { |r| array[r] }
  end
#⇒ #<Proc:0x0055ae3d9ae7c8@(pry):18 (lambda)>
▶ splitter.((1..9).to_a, 3, 4, 2)
#⇒ [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive Array implementation:

```
class Array
  def multi_split(*sizes)
    r = []
    e = self.each
    sizes.each do |size|
      t = []
      size.times do
        t << e.next
      end
      r << t
    end
    r
  end
end

p [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].multi_split(3, 4, 2)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

@Stefan mentioned it might make sense to implement it on Enumerable:

```
module Enumerable
  def multi_split(*sizes)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      e = self.each
      sizes.each do |size|
        yielder << Array.new(size){ e.next }
      end
    end
  end
end

p [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].multi_split(3, 4, 2).to_a
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: For a more versatile implementation, you could `yield` each group and define the method on `Enumerable`.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks. I tried `yielder << e.take(size)` but it outputs `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2]]`. Is there any Enumerable or Enumerable method which could hakes n elements and advanceelp avoid the `size.times` loop?

Comment: Not that pretty, but `yield Array.new(size) { e.next }` would work.

Comment: @Stefan: Much better already, thanks. I was surprised to see that `take` didn't move the internal position forward.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (lossless in event the splits are not equal to the array size

```
def split_at(arr,splits)
  rest = arr.last(arr.size - splits.reduce(:+))
  enum = arr.to_enum
  splits.map do |n| 
    n.times.map { enum.next } 
  end.concat(rest.empty? ? [] : [rest])
end
```

Then called as

```
split_at (1..9), [3,4,2]
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
split_at (1..22), [3,4,2]
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]]
```

[Example](https://repl.it/KaKR/4)

Comment: This is the name I would have used.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def split_by_number(*sizes)
    sizes.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| a << [a.empty? ? 0 : a.last.sum, n] }.
          map { |start, nbr| self[start, nbr] }
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].split_by_number 3, 4, 2
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Note that

```
[3, 4, 2].each_with_object([]) { |n,a| a << [a.empty? ? 0 : a.last.sum, n] }
  #=> [[0, 3], [3, 4], [7, 2]]
```